# Difficulty Reading XML File

Tags: android

Using Eclipse 3.7.2
Android 2.3.3 / API Level 10

I am having trouble reading an XML file. I "think" I get a proper handle on the file with this code and open it for input / output as I will want to read the info, display for user, then update with any changes.

Coming from the c# world when I goto read the file I see a behavior I am unfamiliar with. In the debug perspective my variables have red square values. Now this may be OK but my first thought is red == trouble? However the data (the data in the variables window of the debug perspective) seems ok so I proceed. My eventType is a zero and I enter into the case statement but then I throw an exception. Now here I drop the ball. I don't know how to get more information about exceptions in Java. For example in the c# world I could get the inner exception. I'm sure there is a way in Java I just haven't learned yet.

Here are the steps:
From line 1 I jump straight to line 9. <kbd>F6</kbd> (Eclipse debug shortcut for "Step over") takes me to line 4, <kbd>F6</kbd> again back to line 9, <kbd>F6</kbd> a final time and  I goto my catch for a generic exception.

```
  try
  {
      DataFileOut = new FileOutputStream(LiftFile);
      DataFileIn = new FileInputStream(LiftFile);
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(DataFileIn);        

      // auto-detect the encoding from the stream    
      parser.setInput(isr);    
      int eventType = parser.getEventType();    
      Category currentCategory = null;
      boolean done = false;    
      while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done)
      {        
          String name = null;
  0       //eventType = 2;
  1       switch (eventType)
          {
  3         case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
  4         break;

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
        ....
       }
  9     eventType = parser.next();
   }
}
```

So my thoughts are I have a bad FileInputStream handle or my XML document is not well formed?? Any other thoughts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ExcersiseInformation>
       <Lifts count="6">
          <Lift>
       <ID>1001001</ID>
       <Name>Hammer Curls</Name>
       <PreviousLift>45</PreviousLift>
       <PreviousReps>8</PreviousReps>
       <SuggestLift>45</SuggestLift>
       <SuggestReps>10</SuggestReps>
       <ActualLift></ActualLift>
       <ActualReps></ActualReps>
          </Lift>
          .....
      </Lifts>
   </ExcersiseInformation>
```

Comment: F6 is Step Over, if I'm not mistaken (go to the next line of executed code). @user1278561: Open the Logcat window; you should see your exception in red along with the stack trace showing the exception type and the line of code that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml seems to be well formed. Are you using a handler and parser class to get xml tag contents? Probably best method to reach it. You can find some good examples on internet or other posts. Please take a look to following one, same method that I am using successfuly

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example

Comment: That tutorial was great and the SAX parser is better anyway..now that I am familiar with it I won't be going back to DOM soon.